# How to compare two image files contents in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to compare two image files (.png) basically reading two .png files and assert if the contents are equal.

I have tried below,

```
def read_file_contents(file1, file2):
     with open(file1, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
        contents1 = f.readlines()
        f.close()
     with open(file1, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
        contents2 = f.readlines()
        f.close()
     return {contents1, contents2}
```

then to assert if both the contents are equal I use

```
 assert contents1 == contents2
```

but this gives me assertionerror. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Look at the Pillow and ImageHash modules.

Comment: You are comparing to list why don't you Try  that `if contents1 == contents2: `

Comment: So you want to compare two image files (.png, .jpeg) to determine their potential similarity?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Image files can look the same but be very different to a computer. Things like format, encoding, color space all matter and can make a comparison act differently than you might expect.

Comment: I would suggest Python Wand, which use ImageMagick. It has a compare tool. Or OpenCV template matching. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an *exact* match, you can compare the bytes directly:

```
def validate_file_contents(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'rb', errors='ignore') as f1, open(file2, 'rb', errors='ignore') as f2:
        contents1 = f1.read()
        contents2 = f2.read()
    return contents1 == contents2
```

You could use an `assert` if you want, but personally I'd check the `True`/`False` condition instead.

You also had a few errors in your code:

1. The content within the `with` block is not indented.
2. In a `with` block you don't need to `close()` the files.
3. You are returning a `set` of `content1` and `content2`, where if they are actually equal, you will only have 1 item returned.  You probably wanted to `return (content1, content2)` as a tuple.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex This is assuming OP wanted to check if the files are an *exact* match, i.e. byte to byte, based on their original code.  But if they wanted a full/fuzzy visual match then an imaging library will need to be used.

Comment: your code didn't work when I tried to compare 2 images.  I got it to work after I remove the errors='ignore' piece.

Comment: how can i remove the file2 after reading os.remove is the way to do?

Comment: `os.remove` would work.  I'm still unsure what you are trying to achieve here though.

Comment: after comparing the images i want to remove the images from the folder just to keep it clean.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this task using various Python libraries, including numpy & math, imagehash and pillow.

Here is one way (which I modified to only compare 2 images).

```
# This module is used to load images
from PIL import Image
# This module contains a number of arithmetical image operations
from PIL import ImageChops

def image_pixel_differences(base_image, compare_image):
  """
  Calculates the bounding box of the non-zero regions in the image.
  :param base_image: target image to find
  :param compare_image:  set of images containing the target image
  :return: The bounding box is returned as a 4-tuple defining the
           left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate. If the image
           is completely empty, this method returns None.
  """
  # Returns the absolute value of the pixel-by-pixel
  # difference between two images.

  diff = ImageChops.difference(base_image, compare_image)
  if diff.getbbox():
    return False
  else:
    return True

base_image = Image.open('image01.jpeg')
compare_image = Image.open('image02.jpeg')
results = image_pixel_differences (base_image, compare_image)
```

I have additional examples, so please let me know if this one does not work for you.

Comment: thanks i am using selenium in python and says no module named PIL found.

Comment: PIL (pillow) is another module that you have to import.  Also your question contains no selenium code.

Comment: hmm but i doing this along robot framework...somehow it says PIL not found.

Comment: i was trying to use pillow library. installed pillow using pip install pillow. and used the above code. it gives str object has no attribute load. not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What type of files are you loading?  If they are image files, what size are these files?

Comment: i am loading png files. and they are of size 1544*638 pixels

Comment: I just tested 2400x1800 images and received no errors.  How are you passing the file names to Image.open()?

Comment: sorry. i was passing the filenames from robot tests and forgot to open to read them. now it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using selenium as a tag here is a right choice but w/e.

Images can and are represented as bunch of pixels (basically numbers) arranged in such way that makes them what they are.
The idea is to take those numbers with their arrangement of both pictures and calculate the distance between them, there are multiple ways to do so like MSE.
For the code it self and a further explanation please check out the link below.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Good luck buddy! (:

Comment: A link does not make a good answer because websites don't stay alive forever.  If you find the content useful it should be included locally as part of your answer.  The link only serves as a reference.

Comment: Will immediately be fixed.